# Replacing the Text of the Html Response received in android

Tags: android, string, response, replace

I have got the Html response from the server that I have stored in a string variable named "response" Now I want to scan that string variable and take the selected tags from that string and add them to another string and display them.

Somebody told me about the string replacement but I don't have an idea.

Can anybody tell me how can I do that thing?

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 1):

You can get the sub string from the response and append to your string. Please see

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html

Good Luck

jse

Answer (score 0):

I think the android-spring plug-in can help u on that problem,
here the server response can be easily converted to Java object(Plain old Java Object).
please go through the link
http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html